# QCoreApplication.translate() and mypy result in error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, pyside6

When using:

```py
self.translate("MyCustomClass","This text should be translated", None)
```

in non QObject based classes, mypy will report each call as `Mypy: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "bytes" [arg-type]`. However, the translations work as expected.

But when I try to fix the error detected by mypy with:

```py
self.translate(b"MyCustomClass",b"This text should be translated", None)
```

I get the following error:

```bash
ValueError: 'PySide6.QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate' called with wrong argument values:
  PySide6.QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate(b'MyCustomClass', b'This text should be translated', None)
Found signature:
  PySide6.QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate(bytes, bytes, Optional[bytes] = None, int = -1)
```

Is there I fix for this error, which is apparently no real error?

The translate method is defined inside the QCoreApplication is defined with bytes:

```py
def translate(self, context, key, disambiguation, bytes=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """ translate(context: bytes, key: bytes, disambiguation: Optional[bytes] = None, n: int = -1) -> str """
    pass
```

which is propertly the reason why mypy complains

Answer (score 0):

The error can be fixed by installing some pyside6 stubs.

I installed the "Mypy stubs for the PySide6" from [Github](https://github.com/python-qt-tools/PySide6-stubs) via `pip install git+https://github.com/python-qt-tools/PySide6-stubs`

This removes the error for me.